# Is android.os.Build.SERIAL unique?

Tags: android, unique

I would like to use a unique id for android device that works for phone and Tablet. 
(IMEI doesn't work with no SIM card device and sometime MAC Address return null)

I'm not sure is android.os.Build.SERIAL  unique or not.

Does anyone know about this?

Thanks,
Regards.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, but note that it was only added in API level 9, and it may not be present on all devices. To get a unique ID on earlier platforms, you'll need to read something like the MAC address or IMEI.

Generally, try reading *all* the possible IDs, and use whichever are available. [See this article for guidance](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html).

Comment: Hi Graham , I've tried to use getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress() before but some devices return me a null value.

Comment: Yes, that's to be expected. Sadly there is no universally reliable unique ID available across all devices and API levels.

Comment: @GrahamBorland - Is Build.SERIAL really unique ? Can we expect it will be available in all the devices after 2.3 regardless of wifi or non-wifi device ? will it survive device reset and os upgrade ?

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H I am not sure about the uniqueness of the serial number, but can confirm that it does survive device resets and OS upgrades. From my experience, of flashing ROMs and changing kernels, my serial number has not changed. At one point I had changed everything about the phone (firmware, recovery, OS, kernel). Yet the serial number remained the same

Comment: Fair enough since most of app today support starting from Api Level 15

Comment: Since android 10, google not allowed to read IMEI number, so take care for that.

Answer (score 12):

You can use Build serial and android ID to make your own unique id.

```
String serial =    Build.SERIAL;
String android_id =Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                   Secure.ANDROID_ID);

String myKey=serial +android_id ;
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best solution for this topic. because it must be a very bad luck to get the case when the ANDROID_ID is always the same (this can happen, see info in https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) + a non existing SERIAL id.

Comment: Take care because in android 10, reading IMEI and SERIaL number is not allowed.

Comment: @smeet what we do for that in android 10 ?

Comment: @Vrajesh there is no any full proof solution for the same because now android focuses on unique installs, not unique device. So as far as I know we can not get any unique id that uniquely identify device.

Comment: But be careful - Android ID is not suitable for some cases as it changes when factory reset is done.

Answer (score 3):

**If** it is there, then it is **expected** to be unique. But there is no guarantee that this property is set. Also it is API 9. Unfortunately there's no easy way to uniquely identify the device. Some properties like said SERIAL **can** be present, others like ANDROID_ID as NOT unique, some other like MAC depends on presence of WIFI or its state (if wifi module is off, the you may not be able to read its MAC). Some like IMEI cannot be read even device got phone module. So the best approach is to gather as much data as you can, and try to build something you could **most likely** consider unique device ID

Comment: and most can be faked with custom roms

Comment: Yes, hence "**most likely**" in my answer. But tampering with this requires some efforts Joe User not takes so often, so this may fit OP's needs depending of his requirements

Comment: No it is not. It ought to be but it is broken in many ways depending on manufacturer, model etc.

Answer (score 3):

Serial was only exposed in API:9. but you can get it in older versions using reflection. However the docs mention "if available" so I guess don't rely on it.

```
String deviceSerial = (String) Build.class.getField("SERIAL").get(
                    null);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think for unique Id you should used android Id. 
 following is code to get Android Id.

```
String android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID);
Log.d("Android","Android ID : "+android_id);
```

Comment: Every time you do a Factory Reset a new #Android_ID is set to your smartphone. Be careful!

Answer (score 1):

What about a combination of MAC, IMEI and SERIAL ?

You just have to deal with the fact that they all could be non existant esp. on older phones without SIM.

<s>I just find it odd that MAC would return null. This should not be possible imho, as it makes no sense that a mobile device has no MAC.</s>

There are 2 MAC addresses possible but they can be non accessible in some cases.

Comment: if hardware unit (i.e. wifi) is off, then there's no MAC of it.

Comment: both can be turned off, so should apply to both

Comment: i always received a MAC from bt on my devices

Comment: just checked my S2, even in offline mode the systeminfo shows me the wifi mac. Never played around with this mac but somehow it has to be avail even in offline.

Comment: No, it does not **has to**. It **can**. And it usually do not.