# Where and when is generated android.Build.SERIAL in AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source

I know, that `android.Build.SERIAL` is generated at first device boot, but I can't locate where and when exactly. I'm building `AOSP Jelly Bean`, Android tablet, nosdcard.

2nd question: is this serial number **really** unique for all `Android` devices?

Comment: You can check this link for the uniqueness of the device : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471283/is-android-os-build-serial-unique

Comment: seems like it is unique, but nobody says, that it is 100% unique. I'm building for tablet, which has no IMEI. Getting WiFi MAC address requires WiFi to be started (not the best solution). If android.Build.SERIAL is not unique, then I will write custom ID generator module. But first I need exact information about uniqueness of android.Build.SERIAL

Comment: It's clearly says that it's unique, but added since API 9 and may be not present on all devices.

Comment: "may be not present on all devices" - which device has this id, and which no?

Comment: You told that you're building for a tablet that has no IMEI. Are you building this app for only specific model ? If yes you could direclty check if it has an IMEI. Otherwise, as you said, I recommend you to write a custom ID generator module. You will be sure that your ID will be unique and available for all devices.

Comment: Yes, I'm building for specific model. If I will write custom ID generator, then this should be based on something (ex.: hardware), because if I re-flash my device, I'll lose ID, and new generated ID should be same as previous (before re-flashing)

Comment: that's why I will locae android.Build.SERIAL id generation. For better understaning

Comment: If your device as a serial number. You can go through this process. It's sure it's unique. 2 different devices can't have the same serial number.

Comment: Thank you. Post this comment like an answer, for good karma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471283/is-android-os-build-serial-unique), it clearly says that it's unique, but added since API 9 and may be not present on all devices.

If you're writing your app for a specific device's model, you could direclty check if it has an IMEI. Otherwise, as you said, I recommend you to write a custom ID generator module. 
You will be sure that your ID will be unique and available for all devices.

IMEI represents the serial number of the device. It's sure it's unique. Two different devices can't have the same serial number.

To get the serial number of the device you just have to call :

```
String serial =  Build.SERIAL;
```

It exists another approach. You can get the id by calling [`Secure.ANDROID_ID`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID).

> A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated on the
>   device's first boot and should remain constant for the lifetime of the
>   device. (The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the
>   device.)

```
private final String ANDROID_ID = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Take care because it says that the value **MAY** change if a factory reset is performed.