# Is there a way to prevent or detect duplicated android device?

Tags: android, security

I'm rather new to Android developing (a few months), and I'm developing Android application, that must have some security mechanism, that require licensing per device not per account.

I thinking about the scenario:

- client have a multiple similar Android devices (for example tablet, the same model)
- client buys first license (application gets the license data and store it in the device)
- client create snapshot of first device and use it to make software duplication with other devices (licenses allow to run without internet authorization when user have full commercial license), even after all updates (done in first device)

And here's my question: **is it possible to detect (or prevent) by application that kind of duplication**? *Even with required internet connection in every run (or uuid generated by application instead of getting hardware id), duplicated devices still will be recognized as the same model*...

Or maybe I'm wrong, and that kind of duplication isn't possible?

Comment: May this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645782/where-and-when-is-generated-android-build-serial-in-aosp/16646971#16646971

Answer (score 0):

There are several more or less unique IDs that can be used to identify Android device. See [this example](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/How-to-retrieve-the-Device-Unique-ID-from-android-device) - you may need to use all of them.

On a rooted device with custom build an attacker can obviously fake any ID.

Comment: Yes, i've tested it, some devices (like tablets) can return "unknown" in serial and return no imei data. The best way to combine it. But when you want to run software on all devices you allow also to run on rooted devices. Unfortunatelly, i haven't found way to detect "duplication" on the rooted devices yet.

Comment: That's why you need to use all available IDs - build a single "device fingerprint" from all those IDs (probably using HMAC, but don't trust me on this - ask real cryptographers). If you want to build a 100% reliable copy protection system - forget it, it is not possible.

Comment: But even that fingerprint has some disadvantages... in most cases, when hardware ids aren't available, you have to face with ids generated (at install or Android OS id when system installed), so it's hard to detect did client runs on new device or runs on the same device but in other configuration. I want to implement protection system that won't be annoying for user, but want to allow software also on the rooted devices.

Comment: Please think of it, on a rooted device an attacker can make *any* function return *anything*, they just need need to figure out what you are doing. They can just make your function checkLicense() always return true - once you control Dalvik everything is possible

Comment: Thanks. I'm coding with C++/NDK, which is little harder to break by attacker than coded in java, but in case of that duplication it looks like it's completely transparent to app. There's no 100% working solutions for detecting/preventing when device is rooted (but many of aware users also have rooted devices, so using that kind of security causes hits in typical users not professional attackers). Maybe cloud solutions will provide better security (daily authorization and use cloud storage instead of device memory),but provide less usability (when gsm/wifi signal not reliable).