# UDID or IMEI- which is better?

Tags: android, windows, cordova, udid, imei

When developing an app that requires me to uniquely identify phone users. I was hoping for some advice on whether it is best to use a phone's UDID or IMEI. Are there any advantages/disadvantages to using either. All comments would be greatly appreciated

Comment: May this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645782/where-and-when-is-generated-android-build-serial-in-aosp/16646971#16646971

Answer (score 9):

**Pros of ANDROID_ID:**

1. Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID. This is a 64-bit quantity that is generated and stored when the device first boots (`ANDROID_ID` is not unique for android 2.2 and from 4.2)

**Cons of ANDROID_ID:**

1. `ANDROID_ID` can change on factory reset.
2. `ANDROID_ID` can be `null`
3. It can be easily changed on a rooted phone
4. Several devices by several manufacturers are affected by the `ANDROID_ID` bug in 2.2 and all of them have the same `ANDROID_ID`, which is **9774d56d682e549c**. Which is also the same device id reported by the emulator

   **Docs:** http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html
5. `ANDROID_ID` no longer uniquely identifies a device: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13465373/150016

**Pros of IMEI**

1. [IMEI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity)  number is always unique.

**Cons of IMEI**

1. Many device don't have IMEI number i.e Samsung galaxy tab 2

Important Links

- [android device id confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13744565/1218762)
- http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html
- [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify a device you should try UUID

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html

or maybe try your own identifier. I used a MD5 over the IDs and the MAC-Address, combined with the devices System-Nano-Time. It realy would be a big coincident if two devices have the same "unique ID".